# How to Display image thru CircleAvatar from Database

Tags: flutter, dart

Im Trying to display the image data from database thru CircleAvatar however got some error during the process any suggestion will be appreciated and here the error also **'The argument type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.'**

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
   backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
   backgroundImage: images.map((photo){
       return Utility.imageFromBase64String(snapshot.data[index].profilepicture);
   }),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you got an Iterable type from return data instead of ImageProvider type. If your `snapshot.data[index].profilepicture` is String of URL.

You can just use code below.

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
     snapshot.data[index].profilepicture,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Hi @ShanMichaelReye. Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: Hi @[peter i got this kind of error `Illegal scheme character (at character 6)
Image(image: MemoryImage(Uint8List#843f6, scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, ...
     ^` apologize for the late response